# uniqueness of optimal value when all reduced costs are positive(minimization problem)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I want to prove that if all reduced costs of a basic feasible solution of a minimization problem( linear programming SEF format)are positive, then that Basic feasible solution is the unique optimizer of the problem.

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: I proved it is a minimizer, I am struggling to show it is unique

Comment: [On the Uniqueness of Solutions to Linear Programs](https://www.jstor.org/stable/822972?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)